# Allow user to add data to his sql table row and edit it

Tags: javascript, php

I have a signup form that takes the username,email and password. After you login, there's an option to edit/add more info about yourself. This is where I get stuck, I can't seem to add additional data to the same table 'users' without SQL errors. The code I'm using to add info PHP and form...

```html
<?php 
$error = $fname = $lname = $phone = $location = "";

  if (isset($_POST['fname']))
  {
    $fname = sanitizeString($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = sanitizeString($_POST['lname']);
    $phone = sanitizeString($_POST['phone']);
    $location = sanitizeString($_POST['location']);

    if ($fname == "" || $lname == "" || $phone == "" || $location == "")
      $error = "Enter all fields";
     //put if else statements here
    else if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z_-]/", $fname))
      $error='Remove spaces,numbers,special characters';
    else if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z_-]/", $lname))
      $error='Remove spaces,numbers,special characters';
    else if (preg_match("/[^+0-9]/", $phone))
      $error='Remove spaces,letters,special characters';
    else if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z_-]/", $location))
      $error='Remove spaces,numbers,special characters';
    }
    else
    {
      queryMysql("UPDATE users SET fname = '$fname', lname = '$lname', phone = '$phone', location = '$location' WHERE user = 'sheter'");
      
    }
?>
```

```html
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>" method="post" id="show_signup" class="login">
  <div class="headin">
    <h3>Add Your Details in the Form</h3>
  </div>
  <span id="info"><h3> </h3></span>
  <input type="text" maxlength='16' name='fname' onBlur='checkFname(this)' placeholder="First Name" pattern=".{3,}" required spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" />
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

  <span id="info2"><h3> </h3></span>
  <input type="text" maxlength='16' name='lname' onBlur='checkLname(this)' placeholder="Last Name" pattern=".{3,}" required spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" />
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

  <span id="info3"><h3> </h3></span>
  <input type="text" maxlength='16' name='phone' onBlur='checkPhone(this)' placeholder="Phone" pattern=".{3,}" required spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" />
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

  <span id="info4"><h3> </h3></span>
  <input type="text" maxlength='16' name='location' onBlur='checkLocation(this)' placeholder="Location" pattern=".{3,}" required spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" />
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

  <span class="errormsg"><h3><?php echo $error;?></h3></span>
  <div class="reset"><a href="javascript:clearFormS()">Reset</a>
  </div>
  <button type='submit' value='Submit'>
    <i class="spinner"></i>
    <span class="state">Submit</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

The signup.php has the query as the code below, the blank '', is for user_id set to auto-increment

`queryMysql("INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$user', '$email', '$pass')");
 header("Location:../../index.html");`

And the header imported on all pages is

```html
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'functions.php';

$userstr = ' (Guest)';

if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
  $user     = $_SESSION['user'];
  $loggedin = TRUE;
  $userstr  = " ($user)";
}
else $loggedin = FALSE;

?>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: echo your SQL query, look at it, does it look valid? Is it missing things like quote escapes?

Comment: Exactly which SQL errors are you getting?

Comment: not so much an error more like it's not working

Comment: Is passing an empty string as the I'd valid for your db setup? Is the user actually created? Did you realize you hard coded the user to sheter? Last but not least, do those other fields actually exist?  We really do need to know the SQL error to help...

Comment: yes all fields are created, the 'sheter' part was just a trial, I get to sql errors but when I look at the database nothing has been added. I'm thinking of just adding the above code to the signup form instead of this